# Evaluating $x^3−6x^2+6x$, with $x=2+2^{2/3}+2^{1/3}$. Where did I go wrong here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question has been answered by @Ak and Z Ahmed by posting their answers.

> If $x=2+2^{2/3}+2^{1/3}$, then evaluate $x^3−6x^2+6x$.

So , how I solved is

$$x-2 = 2^{2/3}+2^{1/3}$$

I got
$$x^3 - 8 - 6x^2 +12x = 6+6x-12 $$

Then I got
$$ x^3 - 6x^2 -6x = 2 $$

But not $+6x$.

Yes , answer is $2$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $12 x - 6 x = \color{red}{+}6x$

Comment: Ohk.Thank you @Ak.

Comment: First lines : Please say **where** has this question been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=2+2^{2/3}+2^{1/3} \implies (x-2)=2^{2/3}+2^{1/3}$$
Cubing both sides we get
$$(x-2)^3=2^2+2+3.2(2^{2/3}+2^{1/3}) \implies x^3-8-6x(x-2)=6+6(x-2)$$
$$\implies x^3-6x^2+12x-8=6+6x-12\implies x^3-6x^2+6x=2$$

Comment: Oh! I am saved.